# first elements of each pair from a list

Tags: haskell

I know how to get the first element of a single pair `first (x:_) = x`

but how do I take a list of pairs and return a list of each first item? Do I use a loop or is there any other syntax?

```
[(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)] gives [1,3,5]
```

Comment: Two words: `map fst`

Comment: Your `first` is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In functional languages, one does uses recursion or high order functions like map or fold to iterate over a list. Below, I present some ways of doing it:

1 - List comprehension:

```
firsts :: [(a,b)] -> [a]
firsts xs = [x | (x,_) <- xs]
```

2 - Using map

```
firsts = map fst
```

3 - Using foldr

```
firsts = foldr (\x ac -> (fst x) : ac) []
```

Have some fun!

Answer (score 0):

Fun with monads:

```
firsts xs = do x <- xs; return (fst x)
```